# Using ClientValidationFunction (JavaScript) in an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, validation, updatepanel

I'm trying to determine why my validation function is not being called on my web form.  I've read through various articles at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and most notably found this nugget.

> When you use the CustomValidator control inside an UpdatePanel control, 
>   make sure that the validator control and the control it is associated with 
>   are in the same panel. For more information about using the UpdatePanel 
>   control for partial-page updates, see [Partial-Page Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx) Overview.

With this knowledge I modified my code as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel0" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function IsNotChecked(obj, args) {
                args.IsValid = false;
                if (document.getElementByID("cbRegion0").checked) 
                {
                    args.IsValid = true; return true; 
                }
                return false;
             }
        </script>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRegion0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="0" ClientValidationFunction="IsNotChecked" ErrorMessage="You did not check the box." ValidateEmptyText="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The issue I'm having is that the validation routine does not get executed when clicking the submit button on my page.
Some unique elements of the design is that the code above is actually inside of a .ascx that is added to the page via `Control.Add()` but I don't see how that would affect the ClientValidationFunction.  I believe it's related to the placement of the `<script>` inside the form but despite following directions at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) it doesn't seem to have made a difference. 
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here at Stack Overflow in the [How do I get Client-side validation of ASP.Net page to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944525/how-do-i-get-client-side-validation-of-asp-net-page-to-run) discussion.  Sorry for not seeing this earlier.  As @Brian pointed out, by specifying the `ValidationGroup="0"` in my code that it was expected that the submit button on the page have the same ValidationGroup assigned.  In the end I just removed the attribute from the directive and it now calls the JS.
I found the answer because I was looking through the page source and noticed that the submit button was calling a javascript `WebForm_OnSubmit()` method which ultimately was checking `Page_ValidationActive`.
This led me to the question I've linked.
I hope this helps someone else.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Scripts inside of an UpdatePanel will be lost after an async postback.  Try putting your IsNotChecked method outside of any update panels...  or, implement IScriptControl and put your validation method in the client script file you create to accompany your script control...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems contrary to the article at MSDN but I tried it anyway.  There was no change in behavior.

Comment: @McArthey - just to be clear, I'm not recommending you put the validators outside of the update panel.  Just the scripts being called.  The <script> elements inside of your update panel don't automatically re-register after an async postback...  so, you can re-register and emit them from the code-behind each time there's a postback, you can place the javascript outside of the panel, or you can place the javascript in a file and use IScriptControl to ensure the external JS loads w/ your control each time...  shouldn't be contrary at all to MSDN docs on validators...

Comment: @McArthey - one more thought here - any chance the button you're clicking doesn't have: CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="0" ?

Comment: Ah.. that was it!  Thanks for this.  I have the page built up of a large number of controls and this small detail was obscured.  I also am adding an 'answer' related to this that I found here at StackOverflow.  Thanks again!